The meaning of "Security fixes only" support in older branches of PHP and whether follow such branches is wise in a normal webhosting scenario
I'm a little confused by the meaning of "security fixes only" releases in PHP.
According to its official website:

After this two year period of active support, each branch is then supported for two additional years for critical security issues only.

(emphasis mine)
Does this imply that non-critical security issues are not committed to be fixed? If so, in the scenario of normal webhosting, is it wise security-wise to stay in such a branch (such as 8.1 at the time of writing)?
By "normal webhosting", I meant webhosting that does not require an extremely high security level, e.g., not national defense or critical infrastructure related.
Additionally, the question concerns the PHP package maintained by php.net, not by a Linux distribution.

non-critical security issues are not committed to be fixed?
That is correct. Bug fixes and non-critical security issues are not fixed.

In a typical web hosting scenario, it is unlikely that PHP would be updated directly from the PHP.net. Instead, a version bundled with a Linux distribution is typically used. Long Term Support (LTS) distributions sticks to a certain minor version and keeps backporting security patches for older PHP versions.
As a case study, let's take a look at CVE-2024-3096 (CVSS3 6.5 MEDIUM).

In PHP  version 8.1.* before 8.1.28, 8.2.* before 8.2.18, 8.3.* before 8.3.5, if a password stored with password_hash() starts with a null byte (\x00), testing a blank string as the password via password_verify() will incorrectly return true.

This has been officially fxed for PHP 8.3, 8.2 & 8.1, but backported for many older versions.



Distribution
PHP version
Patch for CVE-2024-3096 (backports in bold)




PHP.net
8.3 & 8.2 (active)  8.1 (security)
8.3.6, 8.2.18 & 8.1.28 (11 Apr 2024)


Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
8.3
8.3.6-0maysync1


Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
8.1
8.1.2-1ubuntu2.17


Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
7.4
7.4.3-4ubuntu2.22


Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
7.2
7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.17+esm3 (Ubuntu Pro)


Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
7.0
7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16+esm9 (Ubuntu Pro)


Debian 12 (stable)
8.2
8.2.18-1~deb12u1


Debian 11 (oldstable)
7.4
7.4.33-1+deb11u5


Debian 10 (LTS)
7.3
7.3.31-1~deb10u6


openSUSE Leap 15.4
7.4
7.4.33-150200.3.65.1




Sorry I should have made it clear. I'm not following a php package maintained by a Linux distribution. I'm interested to know the implication of following a security-fix only branch from php.net.

And you consider that normal webhosting?

The question includes the definition of normal webhosting. Plus, plenty of webhosting happens on Windows, most of which I don't think they have a downstream package maintainer.

Your definition. In that case, Greg Askew's answer is all you need. On the other hand, national defence or critical infrastructure are seldom running on PHP nor related to web hosting.

Based on the case study, at least the php branches on php.net still fix some medium-level security bugs. Maybe they have a different definition of "critical" or they could be toning down their commitment.

Per CVSS system vulnerabilities scoring over 7 (critical & high) are prioritized for fixing. However, vulnerabilities with RCE, privilege escalation or DoS vectors may be considered severe enough to be fixed even with a lower CVSS score.

@xuhdev: Maybe they have a different definition of "critical" or they could be toning down their commitment. they are providing what the majority of customers install, which are only the critical fixes. If you need the other fixes you need to upgrade to a recent supported version.
